# Dynamically creating nested FOR loops based on the list length in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dynamic-programming

Suppose I have a dataset `dt` like this:

| meta_cat | cat | sku | price | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bakery | bread | 796590 | 22.6 | 24 |
| bakery | bread | 796595 | 19.8 | 20 |
| bakery | doughnut | 796588 | 30.6 | 36 |
| bakery | sandwich | 796640 | 45.9 | 42 |
| bakery | sandwich | 796643 | 43.3 | 45 |
| fruits | feijoa | 645342 | 97.2 | 5 |
| fruits | orange | 645675 | 35.7 | 78 |
| fruits | orange | 645677 | 43.9 | 65 |
| fruits | feijoa | 645342 | 92.9 | 11 |

Also, I have a list which looks like this, for example:

```
lvl_list <- list(c("meta_cat"),   
                 c("cat"))
```

I don’t know in advance how many levels there will be in the list (list length can be either 0 (empty list), or one, two, three, etc. (in our example, there are two levels)). List values correspond to the columns names from the dataset.

**My task is to run the nested for loops based on the length of the list.**

If the list is empty, the loop does not start and the `main code` is executed.
If the **list length = 1**, there should be 1 for loop like this:

```
for(i in unique(dt[[lvl_list[[1]]]])){  
    dt <- dt[get(lvl_list[[1]]) == I,] # make subset     
       # run main code   
       # .
       # .
       # main code
     }
   }
```

So, at the first iteration, we filter the `dt` by the first unique value of the `meta_cat` column (for example, choose only records where `meta_cat = "bakery"`) and run `main code` on this `dt`.

If the length of the list = 2, we should get 2 for loops:

```
for(i in unique(dt[[lvl_list[[1]]]])){
     dt <- dt[get(lvl_list[[1]]) == i, ] # filter dt
    
     for(j in unique(dt[[lvl_list[[2]]]])){
       dt <- dt[get(lvl_list[[2]]) == j, ] # filter dt again
       # run main code   
       #  .   
       #  .   
       # main code   
     }
   }
```

So, here we filter `dt` by values of two columns.
There are two unique values ​​for variable `meta_cat` and 5 unique values ​​for `cat` variable.
The logic of code execution should be as follows: at the first iteration, we filter the `dt` by the first value of `meta_cat` (leaving in `dt` observations, where `meta_cat = "bakery"`), at the first iteration of the second loop, we filter the `dt` by the first value of `cat` variable (we will choose observations where `cat = "bread"`). So, we obtain `dt` where `meta_cat = "bakery"` and `cat = "bread"`. Further, this filtered `dt` is used as an input for the modelling code.
On the second iteration, the original `dt` is filtered by `meta_cat = "bakery"`, and `cat = "doughnut"`. Then the main code is executed for this `dt`, end so on.

If there are 3 levels in the list, we should have 3 for loops, etc.

My question: **is it possible to create nested for loops dynamically, based on the list length?**
I would be grateful for any help how it can be implemented.

Comment: Suppose if there are 10 columns, you want 10 inner list?.  Wouldn't that be difficult to extract as well.  Perhaps you want JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier with `split`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(dt, dt[[lvl_list[[1]]]]), function(x) 
         split(x, x[[lvl_list[[2]]]]))
```

---

Also, as this is a recursive split, use `rsplit` from `collapse`, which by default does recursive split and returns the nested list`

```
library(collapse)
lst2 <- rsplit(dt, by = dt[, unlist(lvl_list), with = FALSE])
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(meta_cat = c("bakery", "bakery", "bakery", "bakery", 
"bakery", "fruits", "fruits", "fruits", "fruits"), cat = c("bread", 
"bread", "doughnut", "sandwich", "sandwich", "feijoa", "orange", 
"orange", "feijoa"), sku = c(796590L, 796595L, 796588L, 796640L, 
796643L, 645342L, 645675L, 645677L, 645342L), price = c(22.6, 
19.8, 30.6, 45.9, 43.3, 97.2, 35.7, 43.9, 92.9), sales = c(24L, 
20L, 36L, 42L, 45L, 5L, 78L, 65L, 11L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great solution! But, my list might look like this: ```lvl_list <- list(list("meta_cat"), list("cat", c("bread", "sandwich")))``` or ```lvl_list <- list(list("meta_cat", c("bakery")), list("cat", c("bread", "sandwich")))```.
In the first case, when using `unlist`, I'll get the following set of values `unlist(lvl_list)`: 
`[1] "meta_cat" "cat" "bread" "sandwich"`, while I only need `"meta_cat"`  and `"cat"`. In the second case, I'll get:
`[1] "meta_cat" "bakery" "cat" "bread" "sandwich"`, while I still only need `"meta_cat"`  and `"cat"`. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Hilary Based on the data showed, there is no 'bread' or 'sandwich' columns in the data.  Do you want to remove those elements?.  Then use ` intersect(unlist(lvl_list), names(dt))` and this goes into the `rsplit` i.e. `rsplit(dt, by = dt[,intersect(unlist(lvl_list), names(dt)), with = FALSE])`

Comment: You are right, these are not columns, these are values of a variable. For example, if some variable has 200 unique values, but I want to get a dataset for only 2 values, I should to set these values. If we consider the list ```lvl_list <- list(list("meta_cat"), list("cat", c("bread", "sandwich")))``` - here I want to take all the unique values of the `"meta_cat"` column and only 2 values ```("bread " & "sandwich")``` of the variable `"cat"`. But your approach with `intersect` works, thanks a lot!